# Parsing two-or-more space delimited string with regex using re.findall

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse a string specifying the header of a table using regex in python 3.6:

```py
line = 'Appl.No  Date/Hour              Mass (g ai.ha-1)    Areic mean deposition (mg.m-2)'
```

The column headers are delimited by 2 or more spaces. The individual headers can include *single* spaces, and everything you see above (period, forward slash, etc).
The result should be:

```py
['Appl.No', 'Date/Hour', 'Mass (g ai.ha-1)', 'Areic mean deposition (mg.m-2)']
```

I could do this with use `re.split()` but I also want to use the RE to find the line in a file which contains the column headers so I need to know whether there is a match. In other words I'd like to use `re.findall()` or `re.search()`.

I tried the following:

```py
import regex

regex.findall('([\w./()-]+)( [\w./()-]+)*',line)
```

My idea is that after the first word (`'[\w./()-]+'`) additional words can follow as long as they're preceded by a single space (`'( [\w./()-]+)*'`).

I get:

```py
[('Appl.No', ''), ('Date/Hour', ''), ('Mass', ' ai.ha-1)'), ('Areic', ' (mg.m-2)')]
```

As you can see the "(g" is missing the third match.
Also the matches split into groups, which is not what I want. It's easy enough to merge them, but I was wondering if there's way to apply the '*' to " [\w./()-]+", without specifying separate groups.

Thanks

Comment: Use `re.split(r'\s{2,}', s)`

Comment: Thanks, that works but I forgot to mention that the reason I didn't use ```re.split()``` is because I also want to use the RE to find the line in a file which contains the column headers; i.e. I need to know whether there is a match. Is there a way to mimic ```re.split()``` with ```re.findall()``` or ```re.search()```?

Comment: `re.findall(r'\S+(?:\s\S+)*', s)`

Comment: Thanks, that works! I think the crucial part I was missing is the non-capturing group ```(?:...)```. I'll update my question (not sure if it's still a duplicate then), and add the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'\S+(?:\s\S+)*', s)
```

Or, if you parse a single multiline string and want to stay within line boundaries, use

```
re.findall(r'\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]\S+)*', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UDSFaG/1/).

**Details**

- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\s\S+)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\s` - a single whitespace (a `[^\S\r\n]` only matches a horizontal whitespace if the line endings only include CR and LF chars)
  - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars